# Does the Dragon's Wrath Slumbering quality include the target?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, targeting

I have a question about the newly released Dragon's Wrath Generic weapon variant in *Fizban's Treasury of Dragons*, that includes this specific line of text

> Whenever you roll a 20 on your attack roll with this weapon, each creature of your choice within 5 feet of the target takes 5 damage of the type dealt by the dragon's breath weapon.

When it mentions "Each creature of your choice within 5 feet of the target", does this include the target?

Answer (score 3):

#### The target is within five feet of itself.

The only eligibility requirement is that a creature be within five feet of the creature you hit with the attack. Since zero feet is less than or equal to five feet, the target of your attack is within five feet of the target of your attack, making it eligible for the extra damage.